# Is there any way to show vnstat as indicator Unity?

Tags: unity, networking, indicator, monitoring, vnstat

I tray indicator-netspeed but show sum of download and upload, I want to show each one seperate, Then tray system-monitor-indicator and show total network, I want to show just ppp0 bandwith.

Is there any way to show result of vnstat (vnstat -i ppp0 -l -ru) as indicator?

Answer (score 1):

I've generally found the utilities like vnstat to be problematic.  Whenever I have needed network flow analysis I have used either `iptables` or `scapy` on top of `pcap`

`iptables` example

```
sudo iptables -N measure
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o $INTERFACE -j measure
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i $INTERFACE -j measure
sudo iptables -A measure -m quota --quota $bytequota -m comment --comment "measure" -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -A measure -j REJECT -m comment --comment "exceeded measure"
sudo iptables -A measure -j RETURN
```

This will count bytes on an interface.  Use different rules if you want separate values for input/output.   Very flexible and you can put results into whatever analysis you want (Kafka, google sheet etc).   `Scapy` is far more flexible but I can't provide an example in an answer box....

Answer (score 0):

I use system-load-indicator by Michael Hoffmann.  It shows everything (CPU, net, disk...) but you can selectively turn on what goes into the indicator panel.  Have a look at [that](https://launchpad.net/indicator-multiload).

Install via

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-multiload
```

or a newer version

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:indicator-multiload/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall indicator-multiload
```

Comment: @Daniyal Have you tested the answer? If the answer helped you, click the tick at the left-hand side of the answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I personally wrote a few scripts to work together with my router jiofi.local.html to fetch data.

Whenever I restart the device, the data is reset so I just add it to my previously written data for the same day.

Finally, I used a simple code which uses AppIndicator3 to show it on my Indicator panel. That's it. You can do the same for your router if it's possible. It's the one thing I could guarantee on.

All of this wholly written in python3.

Comment: vnstat and system monitor both don't do a great job, from my personal experience. Especially when there are things like localhost and jupyter notebook to create trouble.